# ETIMEDOUT error not handled

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, timeout

total noob here. Trying to use the npm module 'ttsbackup', which does not seem to be maintained by the original author anymore. This module downloads a list of files specified.

I'm getting an unhandled ETIMEDOUT error occasionally.

Looking at this code snippet,

```
var downloadUrl = function (toDirectory, url, callback) {
    console.log("downloading: %s", url);
    var out = fs.createWriteStream(path.join(toDirectory, UrlHelper.fileNameForUrl(url)));
    out.on('error', function (err) {
        if (err.message.code === 'ETIMEDOUT') {
            console.log("Request timed out...Retrying.");
            downloadUrl(toDirectory, url, callback);
        }
    });
    request.get(url).pipe(out)
        .on('error', function () {
            console.error("Error! Could not get resource: %s. Continuing, but check your mod after archiving for issues.", url);
        })
        .on('close', function () {
            callback(null, url);
        });
};
```

It should be handled properly, but any timeout error will terminate the node process. I've tried moving the .on('error' function around without luck.

Please help me.

Kind regards.

Comment: you try to handle `WriteStream` timeout error? or you may want to handle `request` timeout.

Comment: both I think. there is an error handler for write stream, and one for request.

Comment: but it's the `WriteStream` timeout error that is giving me trouble.

Comment: I haven't see `ETIMEDOUT` error in the source code no matter `readstream` or `writestream`, i think it is a network error in `http` module or i miss something.